# Synchronizing schema validation across the backend and frontend with Yup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, yup

I'm currently developing an application using Express and React. I'm trying to create a common schema on the backend for validating fields. I'm wondering if it's possible to define the schema in JSON format, use it with Yup for the backend, and pass the schema definition as a response to the frontend for use there as well?